# Extracting from Parenthesis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can you advise How I can extract something in parenthesis in pandas.

I have a column named Origin with Countries. But I have certain data in parenthesis, I want to get that data and replace it in my original data frame.

Any advise.
This is my code so far.

```
df['Nationality'] = df["Origin"].str.split("(")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and specify a regular expression pattern:

```
df['Nationality'] = df["Origin"].str.replace(r'\(|\)', '')
```

This would replace the parentheses in the `Origin`.

If you have other data in the column as well, you could extend the pattern to something like this:

```
df['Nationality'] = df["Origin"].str.replace(r'.*\(|\).*', '')
```

This would replace everything before and after the parentheses, and remove the parentheses as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.extract` with a pattern:

```
pat = '\((.*)\)'

df['Nationality'] = df["Origin"].str.extract(pat)[0]
```

For details, see [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7YyVa9/1).

Comment: @Marielle you're welcome. If it helps, consider upvote/accept the answer.